# Sending an email using Gmail from localhost in Symfony 3

Tags: php, symfony, phpmailer, swiftmailer

I faced lately following problem, that I'm not able to send any mail from my localhost using Gmail with Swiftmailer in Symfony 3

That are my settings in parameters.yml

```
mailer_transport: smtp
mailer_host: 127.0.0.1
mailer_user: xxxx@gmail.com
mailer_password: xxxxx
mailer_encryption: tls
mailer_port: 587
```

And here are the config_dev.yml settings

```
swiftmailer:
    transport: gmail
    username:  '%mailer_user%'
    password:  '%mailer_password%'
```

and the sample code

```
/**
 * @Route("/mail/{name}")
 */
public function mailAction($name)
{

    echo 'tete';

    $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
        ->setSubject('Hello Email')
        ->setFrom('konrad@mydomain.de')
        ->setTo('info@mydomain.de')
        ->setBody(
            $this->renderView(
            // app/Resources/views/Emails/registration.html.twig
                'email/registration.html.twig',
                array('name' => $name)
            ),
            'text/html'
        )
        /*
         * If you also want to include a plaintext version of the message
        ->addPart(
            $this->renderView(
                'Emails/registration.txt.twig',
                array('name' => $name)
            ),
            'text/plain'
        )
        */
    ;
    $this->get('mailer')->send($message);

    return $this->render('main/homepage.html.twig');
}
```

After I'm trying to send some test mail the message is only spooled and I don't see any errors or similar.

Furthermore I've tested it locally with PHPMailer with the settings from above and within that library the sending is working as expected.

Do I need to set something more, when I'm working locally?

Comment: host IP should be Gmail SMTP

Comment: it is according to docu not necessary http://symfony.com/doc/current/email/gmail.html

Comment: Add your sending code please

Comment: @Namoz the code is taken from symfony docu so no extra code from my side is added. I will put the code in second answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

The code from above is working as expected. Even without the specifying the encryption or port or even host. The mails are arriving at my mailbox, but were filtered by my SpamAssassin settings. Problem is solved. Sorry for making issues from nothing :)

Answer (score 1):

The Gmail transport is simply a shortcut that uses the SMTP transport
and sets these options:

```
Option   Value 
 encryption  ssl
 auth_mode login 
 host   smtp.gmail.com
```

You have understood this the wrong way in that you define transport SMTP parameters but it's not actually used because the configuration looks for Gmail transport which Symfony auto configures with the default values for Gmail SMTP, and you only need to provide username and password in the parameters.

```
# app/config/config_dev.yml 
swiftmailer: 
     transport: gmail 
     username: '%mailer_user%' 
     password: '%mailer_password%'
```

the `%mailer_user%` and `%mailer_password%` are expected to be defined in

```
# app/config/parameters.yml 
parameters:
# ...
mailer_user: your_gmail_username
mailer_password: your_gmail_password
```

which I assume you haven't configured properly, because either the `parameters.yml` doesn't have `mailer_user`, `mailer_password` and if it does you have overridden the Gmail default that Symfony uses or are incorrect. 
Either way please take a look at the configurations and fill in only the appropriate values.

Also phpmailer is irrelevant, Symfony uses Swift mailer. It worked with phpmailer because probably you set up the parameters correctly, but Swift mailer reads the configuration `.yml` to make transport objects if the configuration are wrong the transport objects values will be wrong.

Comment: Hmm, but still it seems not to work. I cannot not to use mailer_transport or mailer_host in the parameters, as without this both I get  `"[Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ParameterNotFoundException]
  You have requested a non-existent parameter "mailer_transport". Did you mean this: "mailer_password"?"`

Comment: Very Nice ! Thank You !